# Where should we ask non-desktop/laptop questions?

Tags: discussion

I notice that non destop/laptop questions appear off topic here...Kindles, iPads, etc. Is there a SE site dedicated to asking questions regarding those devices, their configurations, and software?

Comment: It depends. What do you want to ask about?

Comment: @random in this specific case: if (and if so, how) you can change the user agent being used by Chrome that was side-loaded onto a Kindle Fire HD

Comment: In this case it may be better on http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Hmm...the question doesn't have anything to do with ebooks, though.

Comment: Oh right, Kindle Fire http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kindle-fire

Comment: ah...thanks, random! (We have *so many* SE sites these days! :) )

Answer (score 4):

- You can ask about Android tablets on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)
- Ones on iPad go well on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh, and Windows tablets belong here on [su].